# Function to iterate over list, merging results into one data frame

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe

I've completed the first couple R courses on DataCamp and in order to build up my skills I've decided to use R to prep for fantasy football this season, thus I have began playing around with the [nflscrapR](https://github.com/maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR) package.

With the nflscrapR package, one can pull Game Information using the `season_games()` function which simply returns a data frame with the gameID, game date, the home and away team abbreviations.

**Example:**

```
games.2012 = season_games(2012)
head(games.2012)
      GameID       date home away season
1 2012090500 2012-09-05  NYG  DAL   2012
2 2012090900 2012-09-09  CHI  IND   2012
3 2012090908 2012-09-09   KC  ATL   2012
4 2012090907 2012-09-09  CLE  PHI   2012
5 2012090906 2012-09-09   NO  WAS   2012
6 2012090905 2012-09-09  DET  STL   2012
```

Initially I copy and pasted the original function and changed the last digit manually for each season, then rbinded all the seasons into one data frame, `games`.

```
games.2012 <- season_games(2012)
games.2013 <- season_games(2013)
games.2014 <- season_games(2014)
games.2015 <- season_games(2015)
games = rbind(games2012,games2013,games2014,games2015)
```

I'd like to write a function to simplify this process.
My failed attempt:

```
gameID <- function(years) {
  for (i in years) {
    games[i] = season_games(years[i])
  }
}
```

With `years = list(2012, 2013)` for testing purposes, produced the following:

> Error in strsplit(headers, "\r\n") : non-character argument Called
>   from: strsplit(headers, "\r\n")

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

While @Gregor has an apparent solution, he didn't run it because this wasn't a minimal example. I googled, found, and tried to use this code, and it doesn't work, at least in a non-trivial amount of time.

On the other hand, I took [this code](http://www.analyticsandvisualization.com/2014/02/scraping-pro-football-data-and.html) from Vivek Patil's blog.

```
library(XML)
weeklystats = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 14))  # Initializing our empty dataframe

names(weeklystats) = c("Week", "Day", "Date", "Blank",
                         "Win.Team", "At", "Lose.Team", 
                         "Points.Win", "Points.Lose", 
                         "YardsGained.Win", "Turnovers.Win", 
                         "YardsGained.Lose", "Turnovers.Lose",
                         "Year")  # Naming columns

URLpart1 = "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/"
URLpart3 = "/games.htm"

#### Our workhorse function ####

getData = function(URLpart1, URLpart3) {
  for (i in 2012:2015) {
    URL = paste(URLpart1, as.character(i), URLpart3, sep = "")
    tablefromURL = readHTMLTable(URL)
    table = tablefromURL[[1]]
    names(table) = c("Week", "Day", "Date", "Blank", "Win.Team", "At", "Lose.Team", 
                     "Points.Win", "Points.Lose", "YardsGained.Win", "Turnovers.Win", 
                     "YardsGained.Lose", "Turnovers.Lose")
    table$Year = i  # Inserting a value for the year 
    weeklystats = rbind(table, weeklystats)  # Appending happening here
  }
  return(weeklystats)
}
```

I posted this because, it works, you might learn something about web scraping you didn't know, and it runs in 11 seconds.

```
system.time(weeklystats <- getData(URLpart1, URLpart3))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.870   0.014  10.926
```

Comment: Nice investigating! Indeed, didn't test my answer - I will happily guarantee that it works contingent on the `season_games` function working as reported in the question.

Comment: This is great!  While I'm mainly focusing on the nflscrapR package for now, I'm definitely bookmarking this to come back to explore thoroughly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at some popular answers for working with lists, specifically [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) and [What's the difference between `[` and `[[`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the).

There's no reason to put your years in a `list`. They're just integers, so just do a normal vector.

```
years = 2012:2015
```

Then we can get your function to work (we'll need to initialize an empty list before the for loop):

```
gameID <- function(years) {
  games = list()
  for (i in years) {
    games[[i]] = season_games(years[i])
  }
  return(games)
}
```

Read my link above for why we're using `[[` with the list and `[` with the vector. And we could run it like this:

```
game_list = gameID(2012:2015)
```

But this is *such* a simple function that it's easier to use `lapply`. Your function is just a wrapper around a `for` loop that returns a `list`, and that's **precisely** what `lapply` is too. But where your function has `season_games` hard-coded in, `lapply` can work with any function.

```
game_list = lapply(2012:2015, season_games)
# should be the same result as above
```

In either case, we have the list of data frames and want to combine it into one big data frame. The base R way is `rbind` with `do.call`, but `dplyr` and `data.table` have more efficient versions.

```
# pick your favorite
games = do.call(rbind, args = game_list)  # base
games = dplyr::bind_rows(game_list)
games = data.table::rbindlist(game_list)
```

Comment: Yeah... I've quickly realized I need to go back and review various sections of those introductory DataCamp courses.  Thanks for your input!